# Is it okay to make an oath to give money to the poor or fast in return on the condition that something happens?

Tags: halal-haram, oaths

People use to say if this (condition) happen than I will give certain amount of money to poor, or I will fast for, for example 10 days. I want to know is it okay? Promising GOD that please do this (condition) and I will give money to poor with your will, or I will give food to 10 hungry people, or I will fast for 10 days. Please give answer with reference.

Comment: Do you mean Avow?

Comment: Avow is like claim  for example"Before GOD I avow I am innocent".

Comment: Above question is referring to "Before GOD I promise that I will sacrifice for him If he help me to do my work" type thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called Nazr and is an Islamic practice and is mentioned in many Quran verses and Hadiths. This is a contract with God. But Nazr has the related Islamic rules that should be fulfilled.

> And whatever you spend of expenditures or make of vows - indeed, Allah
>   knows of it. And for the wrongdoers there are no helpers.
>   http://tanzil.net/#2:270
>
> [Mention, O Muhammad], when the wife of 'Imran said, "My Lord, indeed
>   I have pledged to You what is in my womb, consecrated [for Your
>   service], so accept this from me. Indeed, You are the Hearing, the
>   Knowing." http://tanzil.net/#3:35
>
> So eat and drink and be contented. And if you see from among humanity
>   anyone, say, 'Indeed, I have vowed to the Most Merciful abstention, so
>   I will not speak today to [any] man.' " http://tanzil.net/#19:26

This is definition of Nazr by Ayatollah Sistani:

> Vow means making it obligatory upon oneself to do some good act, or to
>   refrain from doing an act which it is better not to do, for the sake
>   of, or for the pleasure of Allah.

---

**References and more study:**

[Vow rules by Ayatollah Sistani](http://www.al-islam.org/islamic-laws-ayatullah-al-uzma-sayyid-ali-al-husaini-seestani/vow-and-covenant)

[Vow rules by Ayatollah Makarem](http://www.al-islam.org/a-summary-of-rulings-makarim-shirazi/rules-vows-and-covenants)

[A story about Nazr done by prophet SAWW and Ahl al Bayt](http://www.al-islam.org/islamic-stories/nazr-vow-allah-be-fulfilled)